# Is filtering in SharePoint REST Web Services pre-fetch or post-fetch?

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Is filtering on SharePoint 2013 REST web services (specifically the Lists web service to get the items in a list) done pre-fetch or post-fetch? I have a potential situation where the number of items in the source list could be pretty high; so if the filtering is done post-fetch, the fetch would take pretty long to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the $filter= query option in SharePoint causes the server to filter the results before returning them.

You can inspect the results of the HTTP request to confirm this (either in your browser dev tools or a program like fiddler), but a properly implemented RESTful service will always behave this way (filters/sorting/logical operations/etc. applied server-side).

Comment: Also, fiddler trace confirmed that only the filtered content was fetched by the REST web service.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you call ajax. If you are doing it  jquery document.ready(ajax code ) is post fetched. if you doing it inline i.e. < script > ajax call < script > is pre-fetched.